# Rounding to even in R vs SAS

Tags: r, sas, rounding

I am trying to translate some `SAS` code into `R`.  I am using `SAS Viya` on a remote server and the latest version of `R` on a `Windows 10` laptop.  Apparently the `round` function does not work the same in `SAS` and `R`.  If I divide two vectors and use the `round` function on the result, `SAS` and `R` frequently differ by one.  I have been able to get `SAS` to return the same results as `R` by using the `SAS` function `rounde` instead of `round`.  But I have not been able to figure out how to get `R` to return the same results as `SAS`.  I guess `rounde` in `SAS` 'rounds to even':

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Management/An-oddity-Round-function-Can-somebody-who-has-used-both-R-and/td-p/532678

https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/n02h2rvq30k869n164ccmcwvhqyk.htm

Is there a relatively simple way to get `base R` to return the same results as the `round` function in `SAS`?  Or would doing so require a complex function?  Or is the problem at a deeper level perhaps as described here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160711/how-to-solve-a-problem-with-different-results-in-sas-and-r-due-to-a-number-repre

Perhaps the best thing to do is simply define the rounded results in `R` to be the same as those returned by the `round` function in `SAS` until I have the `SAS` code fully translated?

Here are the vectors, formatted for `R`, that I have been using:

```
hr <- c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4)
cy <- c(990, 1011, 1036, 1085, 1117, 1157, 1203, 997, 1019, 1045, 1096, 1130, 1171, 1220, 1004, 1027, 1055, 1106, 1143, 1187, 1237)
```

Here are the lines of code in `SAS` and `R`.

In `R`:

```
Rpop <- round(cy/hr)
```

In `SAS` this is different from `R`:

```
SASpop=round(cy/hr);
```

In `SAS` this is the same as `R`:

```
SASpope=rounde(cy/hr);
```

Here are the results, formatted in `R`, from the three lines of code above:

```
Rpop.results   <- c(2475, 2528, 2590, 2712, 2792, 2892, 3008, 2492, 2548, 2612, 2740, 2825, 2928, 3050, 2510, 2568, 2638, 2765, 2858, 2968, 3092)
SASpop.results <- c(2475, 2528, 2590, 2713, 2793, 2893, 3008, 2493, 2548, 2613, 2740, 2825, 2928, 3050, 2510, 2568, 2638, 2765, 2858, 2968, 3093)
SASpope.results <- c(2475, 2528, 2590, 2712, 2792, 2892, 3008, 2492, 2548, 2612, 2740, 2825, 2928, 3050, 2510, 2568, 2638, 2765, 2858, 2968, 3092)

SASpop.results - Rpop
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

SASpope.results - Rpop
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Here is functional `SAS` code:

```
data a;
input cy hr ;
cards;
 990  0.4
 1011 0.4
 1036 0.4
 1085 0.4
 1117 0.4
 1157 0.4
 1203 0.4
 997  0.4
 1019 0.4
 1045 0.4
 1096 0.4
 1130 0.4
 1171 0.4
 1220 0.4
 1004 0.4
 1027 0.4
 1055 0.4
 1106 0.4
 1143 0.4
 1187 0.4
 1237 0.4
;

data b;
set a;

SASpop=round(cy/hr);
SASpope=rounde(cy/hr);
SASdiff = SASpop - SASpope ;

proc print;
run;

# Obs    cy        hr      SASpop   SASpope  SASdiff
# 1      990       0.4      2475      2475      0
# 2      1011      0.4      2528      2528      0
# 3      1036      0.4      2590      2590      0
# 4      1085      0.4      2713      2712      1
# 5      1117      0.4      2793      2792      1
# 6      1157      0.4      2893      2892      1
# 7      1203      0.4      3008      3008      0
# 8      997       0.4      2493      2492      1
# 9      1019      0.4      2548      2548      0
# 10     1045      0.4      2613      2612      1
# 11     1096      0.4      2740      2740      0
# 12     1130      0.4      2825      2825      0
# 13     1171      0.4      2928      2928      0
# 14     1220      0.4      3050      3050      0
# 15     1004      0.4      2510      2510      0
# 16     1027      0.4      2568      2568      0
# 17     1055      0.4      2638      2638      0
# 18     1106      0.4      2765      2765      0
# 19     1143      0.4      2858      2858      0
# 20     1187      0.4      2968      2968      0
# 21     1237      0.4      3093      3092      1
```

Comment: `floor(cy/hr+0.5)` in R should match.

Comment: On the sample data, `floor(cy/hr+0.5) - SASpop.results` gives me zeroes. Does it not for you, or is your real data different in some aspect from the sample?

Comment: @JonSpring  My apologies.  It does return zeroes.  I got confused and compared the wrong two vectors.  If you post your comment as an answer I will upvote it and probably accept it tomorrow.